# Where can I find the mapping between an ASCII encoding and its visualization?

Tags: shell, drivers, ascii

I like to override the ASCII output in zsh with custom characters. 0x30 wouldn't be then '0' but for example 'Б'. I don't want just to substitute characters, but to change pixels through custom character defintions. Maybe in the drivers or in the encodings?

Comment: I think you may be looking for [ISO Latin Cyrillic Supplemental](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest-codepages.html)

Comment: The Cyrillic was just an example. My goal is to override the ASCII table with characters of only one dot, so I can use characters to draw pixels on a virtual terminal, similar to drawille.

Comment: Try [downloadable character sets](https://vt100.net/dec/vt320/soft_characters) then

Answer (score 1):

What terminal are you using?

You’re asking how to change the font used by the terminal.

If you’re using a terminal emulator in a windowing system (like `xterm` or similar), you can usually do this through a menu.

If you’re on the console virtual terminal of a *nix machine, that might require compiling the font data into the kernel.

Comment: I'm using a virtual terminal on arch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have just invented the font. However it may be that the unicode drawing characters will be a better fit for what you are trying to do.